# Trouble getting started on my user defined function in R that creates 3 plots.

Tags: r

I am new to R. I've been trying to work on my code but I am having trouble understanding which 'parts' go where. This is the code I was given:

```
df=10
boxplot(rt(1000,df),rnorm(1000),names=c(paste("t,df=",df),"Standard Normal"))            
x=seq(0,1,length=150) 
plot(qt(x,df),qnorm(x),xlab=paste("t, df=",df),ylab="standard 
Normal",main="qq-plot") 
abline(0,1) 
curve(dnorm(x),-3.5,3.5,main="Density Comparison") 
curve(dt(x,df),lty=2,add=TRUE) 
legend("topright",legend=c("standard 
normal",paste("t,df=",df)),lty=c(1,2))
```

I am supposed to create a user defined function that takes df as the input and output 3 types of plots. I need to use: df=5,10,25, and 50.

This is what I have so far. Please dumb it down for me since I'm not very familiar with R terminology and I am not sure I am placing things where they are supposed to go..:

```
my.plot = function(n, df) {
a = rt(n,df)
b=rnorm(1000)
x= seq(0,1,length=150)
qt=qt(x,df)
qn=qnorm(x)
dn=dnorm(x)
ledt=dt(x,df)
n=1000
}
thebox= boxplot(a,b,names=c(paste("t,df=",df),"Stand rd Normal")) #1boxplot.
theplot= plot(qt,qn,xlab=paste("t, df=",df),ylab="standard  Normal",main="qq-plot")     
abline(0,1) 
onecurve= curve(dn,-3.5,3.5,main="Density Comparison") #density curve
twocurve= curve(ledt, lty=2,add=TRUE) 
legend("topright",legend=c("standard  normal",paste("t,df=",df)),lty=c(1,2)
}
return(thebox)
return(theplot)
return(oneplot)
return(twocurve)
}
par(mfrow=c(1,3)) 
my.plot(1000,5)
my.plot(1000,10)
my.plot(1000,25)
my.plot(1000,50)
```

Answer (score 0):

It works like this:
1. Your only input parameter is `df`. So your function will have only one input variable.
2. Since you already have the remaining code functional (i.e. after defining `df`) that code can be used as it is.

Below is a simple implementation from your demo code. You can modify it to suite your needs.

```
my.plot <- function(df) {
  par(mfrow=c(1,3))   
  boxplot(rt(1000,df),rnorm(1000),names=c(paste("t,df=",df),"Standard Normal"))            
  x=seq(0,1,length=150) 
  plot(qt(x,df),qnorm(x),xlab=paste("t, df=",df),ylab="standard 
     Normal",main="qq-plot") 
  abline(0,1) 
  curve(dnorm(x),-3.5,3.5,main="Density Comparison") 
  curve(dt(x,df),lty=2,add=TRUE) 
  legend("topright",legend=c("standard 
                           normal",paste("t,df=",df)),lty=c(1,2))
  par(mfrow=c(1,1)) 
}

my.plot(5)
for(df in c(5,10,15,25)) my.plot(df)
```

Comment: I'm confused by the last two lines.  I think it should be `my.plot(5)`?

Comment: you are right... i had written the function in my console and tested, then customized to original choice...
just updated... do tell me how it works!!

Comment: wow thank you so much for helping me. I tried it out and it does work. The only odd thing is that instead of printing five 1x3 plots, it only prints the last one with df=25. Anyway, thank you Shambho.

Comment: It is actually printing all five, but you are able to see only the last one because the same device is being used to view the plots. 

To test this, try this:
`for(df in c(5,10,15,25)) {Sys.sleep(2);my.plot(df)}`

If you are using RStudio, you can click the back button to see previous plots. Or you can just save the plots to files from with in for loop.